# Unix Flex Regex for Multi-Line Comments

Tags: regex, unix, flex-lexer

I am making a Lexical Analyzer using Flex on Unix. If you've ever used it before you know that you mainly just define the regex for the tokens of whatever language you are writing the Lexical Analyzer for. I am stuck on the final part. I need the correct Regex for multi-line comments that allows something like

```
/* This is a comment \*/
```

but also allows

```
/* This **** //// is another type of comment */
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Can you edit your question to improve the “problem” samples? They need newlines to properly express what you're having problems with, but I couldn't work out where they were missing. (Indenting by 4 spaces makes a paragraph into a sample code section.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are multi-line comments in flex/bison so evasive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145498/why-are-multi-line-comments-in-flex-bison-so-evasive)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You don't match C style comments with a simple regular expression in Flex; they require a more complex matching method based on start states. The [Flex FAQ](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/How-can-I-match-C_002dstyle-comments_003f.html) says how (well, they do for the `/*...*/` form; handling the other form in just the `<INITIAL>` state should be simple).

Comment: Ah, I figured there was a FAQ about it! :) +1

Comment: @Bart: I found it the other day when answering a SO question (on parsing XML CDATA sections, a very similar problem in parsing terms except for the fact that it's *even more important* to do it the right way because the end-section sequence is three characters long).

Comment: If RegEx-only is necessary,"/*"( [^*] | (*+[^*/]) )*\\*+\/ would do the job. I've explained in greater detail in http://stackoverflow.com/a/32320759/3000919

Comment: @DonalFellows please add the answer of that page to your answer. The answer could now get lost.

Answer (score 12):

If you're required to make do with just regex, however, there is indeed a not-too-complex solution:

```
"/*"( [^*] | (\*+[^*/]) )*\*+\/
```

The full explanation and derivation of that regex is excellently elaborated upon [here](http://blog.ostermiller.org/find-comment).

In short:

- `"/*"` marks the start of the comment
- `( [^*] | (\*+[^*/]) )*` says accept all characters that are not '*' (the `[^*]` ) or accept a sequence of one or more '*' as long as the sequence does not have a '*' or a '/' following it (the `(\*+[^*/])`). This means that all '******...' sequences will be accepted except for '*****/' since you can't find a sequence of '*' there that isn't followed by a '*' or a '/'.
- The '*******/' case is then handled by the last bit of the RegEx which matches any number of '*' followed by a '/' to mark the end of the comment i.e `\*+\/`

Comment: I don't think this regex will compile. Flex doesn't accept non-escaped white spaces in patterns. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52977608/3052438

Comment: In any case the problem here is that comments can be arbitrary long and the rules of *lex(1)* and *flex(1)* would require it to accumulate the entire rule before despatching it, which is entirely undesirable.

Comment: @user207421 It depends. If you just want to ignore comments, that can somewhat slow down the lexer without giving any profits but if you want to capture the comment, it is desirable.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-l.html does:

```
"/*"            { comment(); }

comment() {
    char c, c1;

loop:
    while ((c = input()) != '*' && c != 0)
        putchar(c);

    if ((c1 = input()) != '/' && c != 0) {
        unput(c1);
        goto loop;
    }

    if (c != 0)
        putchar(c1);
}
```

A question which would also solve this is [How do I write a non-greedy match in LEX / FLEX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166194/how-do-i-write-a-non-greedy-match-in-lex-flex)

Comment: If anyone can guess why the downvote, I'd love to hear.

Comment: Not a downvote here - but that fails for even asterisks:
/**
hello
****/
printf("lol");
/** hmmm */
The reason is the \*[^/] will consume two *s at a time if the * is not followed by a /

Comment: @AbrahamPhilip thanks! My regex was wrong, and yours seems right. Removed it from the answer.

Comment: np, glad to be of help :)